# how save pointer address after free the pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have written a code which at first creates a memory alloc and save a string in an other pointer. According to the code, the value must be kept in an other address after free but it gives an error "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer".

My Code is :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "testfunc.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
static char *server_alg;
char *test;
char *test = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
server_alg = "A";
strcpy(test, server_alg);
printf("server_alg addr = %u \n", &*server_alg);
printf("server_alg value = %u \n", server_alg);
printf("SERVER_ALGO addr = %d \n", *server_alg);
free(server_alg);
server_alg=NULL;
printf("           nulled          \n");
printf("server_alg addr = %u \n", &*server_alg);
printf("server_alg value = %u \n", server_alg);
printf("SERVER_ALGO addr = %u \n", test);
printf("SERVER_ALGO value = %u \n", *test);
return 0;
}
```

Is it wrong?

Thx for your helps

Comment: Do not print addresses with `%u` you should cast them to `void *` and use `%p`.

Comment: Why do you declare `test` twice? That will not compile.

Comment: Why do you want to save the address? Any usage of the address will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You are freeing `server_alg`, but you didn't allocate any memory there. Instead, you assigned a string literal to it, so it's pointing to a read-only location in your program's binary:

```
server_alg = "A";
```

After this, you copy from that pointer to `test`:

```
strcpy(test, server_alg);
```

This is correct, as you properly allocated memory for `test` here:

```
char *test = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

Then, however, you try to free it while it is still pointing to `"A"` in your binary:

```
free(server_alg);
```

Instead, try freeing `test`, because that is pointing to the memory you allocated:

```
free(test);
test=NULL;
```

Furthermore, there's an issue with redeclaration here:

```
char *test;
char *test = (char*) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

You're defining `test` twice, best just remove that first line.

Last but not least, I'd change the prints in the end to:

```
printf("server_alg addr = %p \n", server_alg);    // 00D87B30 (or something similar)
printf("server_alg value = %s \n", server_alg);   // A
printf("SERVER_ALGO addr = %p \n", test);         // 00000000
//printf("SERVER_ALGO value = %u \n", *test);
```

`%s` is the specifier that lets you print a string, and `%p` is the one for pointers. I commented out that last print because it would crash the program as `test` is freed and set to a null pointer now, so we can't access its content.

On another note, when you want to copy a string to the heap (be it from a string literal or from a different place on the stack heap), `strdup` can be used to do that. It allocates the appropriate amount of memory so you don't have to worry about that. Call it like this:

```
char *test = strdup("A");
```

When you're done with it, you free it by calling `free(test);`, just like with memory allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: @Black, you must think for yourself. Blaze gave you all the information you need to correct your code.

Comment: I’d recommend at least one other change: `strcpy()` could lead to buffer overflows. It’s better to use another function such as `strncpy()` instead, or in this case, `strdup()`. The OP is not deliberately shooting-yourself-in-the-foot for speed here.

Comment: Great suggestion, I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

following statements are the issues here
    free(server_alg);

you can use free() only when if you allocate memory using one of malloc(), calloc() or realloc() as you have not allocated memory free(server_alg); is wrong, it will lead to memory dump

and we should never try to use pointer once we do free() on it.

Comment: @Osiris as per my understanding for single character 'A' is correct one, if  for string "A" , to be specific 'A' is char and "A" string, in C both are correct, based on the need of string or single char.

Comment: @Osiris agreed string and char behaviour changes

Comment: _"it will lead to memory dump"_, no it will result in _undefined behaviour_, which _might_ manifest itself as segfault, memory dump, crash or whatever.